# 'components' is not defined (no-undef)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

Just added vue to an existing project and I'm getting a weird linting error:

```js
error: 'components' is not defined (no-undef) at src/App.vue:13:3:
  11 | 
  12 | @Component({
> 13 |   components: { HelloWorld },
     |   ^
  14 | })
  15 | export default class App extends Vue {}
  16 | </script>
```

This also happens for every other attribute I add the object.

#### Eslint config

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "@vue/typescript/recommended",
    "@vue/prettier",
    "@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": ["error"],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
        "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)",
      ],
      env: {
        mocha: true,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

#### Package.json

```json
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
```

#### Typescript

I'm using typescript if that's of any concern.

Comment: The error is coming from TS so yeah, it's important in that case because you need to have some minimal configuration for it to work properly. Not sure of what you did already but you may try `import * as Vue from "vue";` above the `@Component` line and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: This one may also help: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the issue is coming from the eslint:recommended package. If I remove that from the extends array, the errors goes away. Other than that, this is the default, vue startup thingy and I didn't change anything. @kissu

Comment: Adding the import does not fix the issue @kissu

Comment: Didn't work with Vue+TS yet but if you think, this is an ESlint issue only, try to install the needed package: `npx install-peerdeps --dev @vue/eslint-config-typescript`. Taken from: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-config-typescript#vueeslint-config-typescriptrecommended

Comment: Sadly not working @kissu I'm going to create a completely new project and copy the stuff I need. Still, if you or anyone else knows a solution, feel free to tell me. I will try it out on the broken project.

Comment: I can also reproduce this with a project generated with Vue CLI `5.0.0-alpha`, which bumped ESLint to 7. The known working versions are `"eslint": "^6.7.2", "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2"`, as seen from a Vue CLI `4.5.10` scaffold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue open on the typescript-eslint repo.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2942

After upgrading with yarn upgrade, the issue disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in no-undef with TypeScript. I couldn't find any information about it, but this solved the issue for me. It thinks 'components' is a variable instead of a property name. Use "components" instead:

```
@Component({
    "components": { HelloWorld },
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
```